# Setting a variable in the tested script via JEST

Tags: javascript, jestjs

This sounds like one of the easiest tasks ever. But I haven't made it nor I could find a solution within an hour of Googleing.

I'm trying to test a Browser Javascript. Therefore I need to pretend that a document.ready / JQuery $(function) was called. What this does really is initializing a variable and calling a function.

So I want my test to initialize a (global) variable in the script and call the script function.

In the example below I'd expect a cosnole.log "true", but I get a console.log "false".

script.js

```
let bDomLoaded = false;

function initCheck() {
  console.log('bDomLoaded:', bDomLoaded);
}

$(function() {
  bDomLoaded = true;
  initCheck();
});
    
//* -------- export for JEST test automation --------
/* eslint-disable */
/* istanbul ignore next */
var module = module || {};
/* eslint-enable */

/* istanbul ignore next */
module.exports = {
  initCheck: initCheck,
  bDomLoaded: bDomLoaded,
};
```

script.test.js

```
... // some magic making html containing the HTML Code of the tested site

const HOK = require('script.js');

describe('Test 1', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = html.toString();
  });

  test('Test 1', async () => {
    HOK.bDomLoaded = true;
    await HOK.initCheck();
    ...
  });
```

Obviously

```
HOK.bDomLoaded = true;
```

in the test is not setting

```
bDomLoaded
```

in the script.

What's the right command to set bDomLoaded in the script?